# Flutter: Enforce CustomScrollview to fill all the remaining space inside SingleChildScrollView between top and bottom widgets?

Tags: flutter

How to enforce CustomScrollview to fill all the remaining space inside SingleChildScrollView between top and bottom widgets? shrinkWrap=true on CustomScrollView is not a solution as it will shrink the CustomScrollView itself, and I need to stretch it as there is a pull-to-refresh list there

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
      children: [
        Text("This is the top widget"),
        // ScrollView widget needs to fill all remain space between top and bottom widgets
        MyScrollView(),
        Text("This is the botton widget"),
      ],
    ))));
  }
}

class MyScrollView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyScrollView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green, // this needed to see actual size
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                        child: Text("Text $index"),
                      ),
                  childCount: 10))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```